# How to enable stapling or print jobs with CUPS on linux?

Tags: cups, ipp

I have a Xerox AltaLink printer that supports stapling.  I can print and staple a job if I go to the embedded web server and upload a document to print with my browser, but it would be much more convenient to be able to print with `lpr` and from within applications such as PDF viewers.  I'm using linux with CUPS 2.4.2.

When I run `ipptool -tv ipp://altalink.mydomain.com/ get-printer-attributes.test`, the output includes:

> finishings-supported (1setOf enum) = none,staple,punch,punch-dual-left,bind,edge-stitch,jog-offset,staple-top-left,staple-bottom-left,staple-top-right,staple-bottom-right,edge-stitch-left,edge-stitch-top,edge-stitch-right,edge-stitch-bottom,staple-dual-left,staple-dual-top,staple-dual-right,staple-dual-bottom,punch-dual-left,punch-dual-top,punch-dual-right,punch-dual-bottom,punch-triple-left,punch-triple-top,punch-triple-right,punch-triple-bottom

So it seems like all I need to do in the printer job menu is set `finishings` to `staple-top-left` to get what I want.  Unfortunately, when I use `system-config-printer` to add the printer and edit its properties, the only available option for `finishings` is `None`.  If I go to the cups embedded web server on port 631, I get even fewer options.  And in the system print dialogs, I don't get any option for finishings.

How can I enable stapling either as a default for all jobs (my preference) or at least on a per-job basis?